# When I use Chinese.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-15: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, http, url, encoding

```
def google_search(key_word):
    query = "https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=" + key_word +"%20site:detail.zol.com.cn"
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}  
    req = urllib.request.Request(query,headers=headers)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
return page
```

when I use this function with a english keyword, it works fine. But when I use chinese such as google_search(key_word="魅族 魅蓝Note"), I got an Error in 5th line:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 14-15: ordinal not in range(128)

so how can solve this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you from shenzhen?

In fact, chinese string needs to be "urlencode" in url.

It seems you use python3, i am not familiar with python3, let me use python2 to explain it, what you can do is to replace the api i have used in the example.

```
#coding:utf-8
import urllib
key = urllib.quote("魅族 魅蓝Note")
google_search(key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I have tried too many times, google report a 503 error. So I have to try your method latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import quote

def google_search(key_word):
    query = "https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=" + quote(key_word) +"%20site:detail.zol.com.cn"
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'}  
    req = urllib.request.Request(query, headers=headers)
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    return page
```